# Resize all elements including draggable images on a screen upon window resize in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to resize all elements on a web page upon resizing the window. The background image needs to stretch along with draggable items, text boxes, font size, and other images. The draggable items needs to stay in the same place in proportion to the background image. Everything needs to maintain aspect ratio. I have tried numerous methods and none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the background image scaling to whatever is going on on the page, see my reply to this guys similar question.

[resize the image to fit the dimensions of TD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518441/resize-the-image-to-fit-the-dimensions-of-td/12518664#12518664)

as far as other objects changing but maintaining aspect rations you may want to look into css Media Queries.

good luck