# css adjust image with set width to table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with images and text content, these images have a set width using:

```
<img src="" width="250">
```

Some of these images are added to the tables dynamically during runtime with jQuery. If a really large image is added, the table width become larger than screensize. I have in my CSS for table `width:value of its container`.

How can i make the images shrink so the table never gets bigger than it's width in pixels? I don't want to remove the width tag from the image.

Comment: Check this question on stack**overflow**: [resize the image to fit the dimensions of TD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518441/resize-the-image-to-fit-the-dimensions-of-td)

Comment: BTW: Google not online?  search:"css scale image to fit table cell"

Answer (score 0):

You can set the with via CSS:

```
img{
        width:100%; height:auto;
}
```

Also, instead of using an image tag, you could use the table cell itself. For example:

```
 <td class="image"></td>
```

And then styling that image class for the cell:

```
.image {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/fWmztPH.jpg);
}
```

I put a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7bbcf2cy/

Answer (score 0):

if your image is in `td` like

```
<td>
    <img src="#" width="250">
</td>
```

add css style in your code (but don't forget to delete 1 line with comment)

```
td img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%; /* if td size is definied, and image must be fullwidth */
    max-width: 250px; /* if you want images not to be larger than 250px */
    height: auto;
}
```