# Non-Chrome browsers diplay table in a weird way

Tags: html, css

I have a table element like this

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.tab {
  width: 100%;
}
.tablepadding {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="tab">
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>picture.jpg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

The content is displayed normally in Chrome and Edge as it should be. The problem I have is that in Firefox or IE the picture is basically full size and the constrains are just ignored. How would I fix that?

Also I have another issue. I have an element that has height set to 100vh. In Chrome it works perfectly setting its size just right to display over the whole screen. Every other browser does not do that. How would I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the picture as an actual image or just the text?

Comment: I think you made an error in the copy and paste bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resize the image to fit the dimensions of TD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518441/resize-the-image-to-fit-the-dimensions-of-td)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The content is displayed normally in Chrome and Edge as it should be. The problem I have is that in Firefox or IE the picture is basically full size and the constrains are just ignored. How would I fix that?

1. Use `table-layout: fixed` CSS property and value in order to control the table. Notice in the demo I have set the td widths to 20% and 80%, and set the height to 200px.

> Also I have another issue. I have an element that has height set to 100vh. In Chrome it works perfectly setting its size just right to display over the whole screen. Every other browser does not do that. How would I fix this?

2. Try `min-height: 100vh` I applied it to the div with class `.overlay` in demo.

```css
div {
  max-width: 500px;
}
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
td:first-child {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
}
td:last-child {
  width: 80%;
}
.tablepadding {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 5px solid red;
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='overlay'>
  <table class="tab">
    <tr>
      <td>text</td>
      <td>picture.jpg</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```